# Potential for bias to be introduced when limiting analysis to participants who seek treatment?

Tags: bias, confounding, ab-test

I am running an online AB test where users are assigned to condition (test or control) at login, but only 1/3 of assignees reach the feature being tested.

Analyzing all assignees will give me an accurate estimate of the effect of releasing the test version of the feature in the full user population, but this intent-to-treat analysis will also water down the estimate of the new feature's effectiveness among actual users, a separate but important question.

So if I analyze only the 1/3 of users who actually use of the feature (a per protocol analysis) **is it possible I am introducing bias into my analysis, bias that would not be protected against by random assignment to condition**? Is there any reason to think that my sample of feature users is different than if I had randomized at the moment they reached the feature rather than at login?

Assume there is no way that users would know they were in a given condition, there is no way for users to access the alternative condition, and there are equal rates of the feature's use in both conditions. Is there any reason not to assume sequential ignorability: That use of the tested feature was still as random as assignment to condition? Have I possibly introduced unmeasured confounding when I perform the per protocol analysis?

Comment: It's possible to consider this a type of *Heckman selection bias*. Heckman's two stage model is an approach for reducing downstream bias in data that has seen successive reductions in size from the full, original data. Based on your description, your situation is similar. Basically, Heckman's solution would add a new feature or parameter to your final model that represents a type of *weight*, where the final data is adjusted to more accurately reflect the original data's composition. Remaining observations more strongly similar to the original, full data are given more weight in the final data

Comment: See Heckman's original paper here...https://math.la.asu.edu/~prhahn/Heckman79.pdf  There are lots of programs out there which run his method for different software.

Comment: You might consider an instrumental variables analysis with experiment as the IV. The experiment satisfies the exogeneity ass. You also need the users in T to reach the feature more than users in C, which is testable. Moreover, the entire difference in outcomes between T and C comes from additional people who interact with the feature. You also can't have people who reduce use because they don't like the experimental encouragement. This is untestable, but could be motivated by domain knowledge.

Comment: Under the assumptions above this would estimate the effect of reaching the feature for people who are swayed to reach the feature by their experimental assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimating the per-protocol effect does not introduce confounding bias because there are no confounders. I think a reasonable DAG based on your description might be:

$$A \rightarrow F \rightarrow Y \leftarrow U \rightarrow \boxed{R}$$
where $A$ is assignment to treatment, $F$ is which version of the feature is actually seen), $Y$ is your outcome, $R$ is whether someone reached the feature, and $U$ is the unmeasured causes of the outcome and the failure to reach the feature (e.g., interest in the product). Conditioning on $R$ by only looking at those who reached the feature does not introduce any noncausal associations between $F$ and $Y$; no backdoor paths are opened and no frontdoor paths are blocked.

The main issue is that your estimand is different when you condition on reaching the feature; it is now a conditional, rather than marginal, estimand. It generalizes only to those who would be inclined to reach the feature, and not to those who would not be inclined to reach the feature. If the effect of the feature differed, for example, between interested users and uninterested users, then the estimated effect among those who reached the feature would not represent the effect of the feature in the total population of users. In your case, this is actually desirable; unless you force all users to reach the feature, you really are only interested in the effect of the feature on those who reach the feature.

If the DAG is incorrect, then it is possible for biases to be introduced, even in estimating the conditional effect. If users were clued into to which feature they might receive ($A$) and that influenced whether they reached it or not (i.e., adding the path $A \rightarrow U$ or $A \rightarrow R$), conditioning on reaching the feature ($R$) would induce collider bias. As you have described it, this is not an issue. The only issue is the population to which the effect generalizes.

Comment: thank you for such a clear and thorough response. My concern grew out of reading about problems with causal inference in mediation: that mediating variables cannot be assumed to be randomized just because condition is randomized. We are often not justified to assume sequential ignorability. Your explanation above was so clear I was wondering if you could shed light on this topic as well. If I can assume that my subgroup of blind users who reach the feature are an unbiased subgroup, why can I not also assume that mediating variables do not confound my model. Again thank you.

Comment: Mediators confound the model when you condition on them. You did not condition on any mediators here. Mediators are variables that are caused by treatment and that cause the outcome. $F$ is your treatment variable, and you never condition on a mediator ($R$ is not a mediator because it is neither caused by treatment nor causes the outcome).

Comment: yes I know that my model has no mediators. Since you seem to have a really strong grasp of this topic are there any resources you'd recommend for getting a strong grasp of when and how mediators can confound analyses?

Comment: Yes! I strongly recommend [Elwert and Winship (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-soc-071913-043455) for a nice introduction to these issues. It's very accessible and oriented toward applied researchers, while the source material (Judea Pearl's work) can be a little technical at times.

Comment: thank you this is very helpful!

Comment: I find the DAG a bit strange. Suppose the treatment is encouraging a user to install a dating app and you want to measure the effect of actually installing on dates. Your estimated effect would compare average number of dates from users who installed the app in T to all users who did not see an encouragement. I suspect there is an unmeasured variable called interest in dating, and people who are interested install the app more because they plan to date more and and the app makes that easier. The DAG is A->F->R->Y<-U and also U->R, so the measured effect is a combo of selection and app effect.

Comment: According to OP's description, $R$ (whether the feature was reached) precedes $F$ (which feature was reached), so I don't think your DAG is accurate. The target population of the marginal effect is all app users, and the target population of the conditional estimand (i.e., conditional on $R = 1$) is app users who are interested enough to reach the feature. In your example, I assume $A$ is encouragement, but in OP's story, compliance is perfect among those who reach the app (i.e., $A = F$).